# Que comportamiento tiene case a:Int => a

Tags: blockchain, solidity

[image: https://ucarecdn.com/39873ac9-12ae-4235-a457-879e00a2ddec/]

> Las instrucciones del código que no entiendo son los relacionados con:
>
> case a:Int => a
>
> analogamente:
>
> case a:String => a

Comment: Por favor añade tu código como texto

Comment: Esto no es [tag:c].

Comment: Disculpen el uso de la imagen pero es que stackoverflow no soporta el codigo del lenguaje RIDE.

Answer (score 1):

Cuando te indica en el código

```
Case a:int => a
```

Indica que en el caso en el que 'a' sea de tipo Integer devuelva 'a' y en caso contrario '0', por otro lado:

```
Case a:String => a
```

Es el mismo caso, pero en este caso si 'a' es de tipo String lo devolverá y sino devuelve el texto entrecomillado como excepción.